# C++ program killed by OOM

Tags: c++, exception, memory, out-of-memory, gurobi

I have a C++ program calling Gurobi and running on Ubuntu 20.04. I am solving a Mixed Integer Linear Program (MILP), and I need to return the best solution found after a time limit. However, the program was killed before this time limit for some instances without returning the solution. The output of `dmesg` shows that the program was killed by OOM

```
[  +0,000003] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service,task=LB,pid=56262,uid=1000

[  +0,000014] Out of memory: Killed process 56262 (LB) total-vm:5345884kB, anon-rss:5174060kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:10232kB oom_score_adj:0
```

I used Valgrind to see if I have a memory leak, but it seems that I don't have

```
==67757== HEAP SUMMARY:
==67757==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==67757==   total heap usage: 4,184,293 allocs, 4,184,293 frees, 4,996,993,663 bytes allocated
==67757== 
==67757== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==67757== 
==67757== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Header file of my code

```
    class MILP
{   
    GRBEnv env = GRBEnv();
    GRBModel model = GRBModel(env);

    GRBVar fun;
    std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>> inter;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>>>> r;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>>>> R;
    
   
    void addvars();
    void addconstr();
    void addobj();

    void getobjval();

    void setparameters();

    int solvemodel();

public:

    int runMILP();
   };
```

The .cpp

```
    void MILP::addvars()
    {
        
        fun=model.addVar(0, data::M, 0.0, GRB_CONTINUOUS, "");
    
        inter.reserve(data::P.size());
    
        for (int i = 0; i < data::P.size(); ++i)
        {    
            std::vector<GRBVar> row;
            row.reserve(data::P[0].size());
    
            for (int j = 0; j < data::P[0].size(); ++j)
            {
               row.push_back(model.addVar(data::P[i][j], data::M, 0.0, GRB_CONTINUOUS, ""));
            }
    
            inter.push_back(row);
        }  
        
        // variable R
        R.reserve(data::P.size());
    
        for (int i = 0; i < data::P.size(); ++i)
        {
    
            std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>>> threeDarray;
            threeDarray.reserve(data::P.size());
    
            for (int u = 0; u < data::P.size(); ++u)
            {
    
                std::vector<std::vector<GRBVar>> matrix;
                matrix.reserve(data::P[0].size());
    
                for (int j = 0; j < data::P[0].size(); ++j)
                {
    
                    std::vector<GRBVar> row;
    
                    if (j != 0)
                    {
                        row.reserve(j);
                        for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
                        {
                            row.push_back(model.addVar(0, (data::M - data::P[i][j] - data::P[u][k]), 0.0, GRB_CONTINUOUS, ""));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.reserve(1);
                        row.push_back(model.addVar(0, 1, 0.0, GRB_BINARY, ""));
                    }
                    matrix.push_back(row);
                }
    
                threeDarray.push_back(matrix);
    
            }
            R.push_back(threeDarray);
        }
    }
    
    void MILP::addconstr(){
        
        for (int i = 0; i < data::P.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < data::P[0].size(); ++j)
            {
                model.addConstr(fun >= inter[i][j]);
            }
        }
    
     
        for (int j = 0; j < data::P[0].size(); ++j)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k)
            {
                if (data::C[j][k] == 1)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data::P.size(); ++i)
                    {
                        for (int u = 0; u < data::P.size(); ++u)
                        {
                            if (u != i)
                            {
                                GRBLinExpr lhs = inter[i][j] -inter[u][k] + data::M * r[i][u][j][k] - data::P[i][j];
                                model.addConstr(lhs == R[i][u][j][k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    void MILP::addobj()
    {
       GRBLinExpr obj = fun;
       model.setObjective(obj);
    }
    
    void MILP::setparameters()
    {
    
        model.set(GRB_IntAttr_ModelSense, GRB_MINIMIZE);
            
        // limit the time spended
        model.set(GRB_DoubleParam_TimeLimit, 1800);
    }
    
    
    int MILP::solvemodel(){
    
        model.optimize();
    
        int status = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_Status);
    
        return status;
    }
    void MILP::getobjval()
    {
        objvalue = model.get(GRB_DoubleAttr_ObjVal);
    
    }

   
   int MILP::runMILP()
    {
        try
        {
            addvars();
            addconstr();
    
            setparameters();
            addobj();
            
            model.update();
    
            int status = solvemodel();
    
    
            if (status == GRB_OPTIMAL || status == GRB_TIME_LIMIT)
            {
                getobjval();
                return 1;
            }
            else if (status == GRB_INF_OR_UNBD ||
                     status == GRB_INFEASIBLE ||
                     status == GRB_UNBOUNDED)
            {
                std::cout << "The model cannot be solved because it is infeasible or unbounded" << std::endl;
    
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Optimization was stopped with status " << status << std::endl;
    
                //freevariables();
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (GRBException e)
        {
            std::cout << "Error code = " << e.getErrorCode() << std::endl;
            std::cout << e.getMessage() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "Exception during optimization" << std::endl;
        }
   
        return 0;
    }
```

Is there a way to prevent the program from being killed by stopping the call to Gurobi before having an out of memory and thus allow the next iteration to be processed? And how to return the best solution found so far by the solver?

Comment: You may be freeing every piece of memory you attempt to allocate, but if you're still attempting to reserve 5GB of memory that could be an issue. Without seeing any of your actual code it's hard to tell if there's something you're doing that wastes memory without actually rising to the level of a Valgrind-detectable leak or if that's just the footprint required for the algorithm you're invoking.

Comment: @NathanPierson I edited my question by sharing the code

Comment: @NathanPierson I am a beginner in handling exceptions, but I am wondering if it is not possible to track the memory usage and stop the call to Gurobi before being killed?

Comment: The program uses too much memory, that's pretty much it. Either this specialized algorithm requires special, dedicated-purpose hardware that's appropriately scaled for the task at hand, or it's the wrong algorithm. This happens very often with many coding puzzles from any one of countless of web sites that promise to turn anyone into a C++ superhacker simply by solving a bunch of useless coding puzzles. Those puzzles are always based on some mathematical or a programming trick. If someone doesn't know it, and tries a brute force approach, it always takes up too much memory or runs too slow.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am using my personal computer with 7,6 GiB. The call to the solver is consuming memory.  However, what I need now is not to kill the program, but to stop the call to the solver once we run out-of-memory, return the best solution found and continue processing the next iterations of the program.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible for the highly technical reason that's called "the cat is out of the bag". By the time the OOM killer decides to kill a process, there's nothing that can be done to change its mind. The decision is final. About the only thing that can be done is to determine how much memory is safe to allocate before the OOM killer kicks in, and impose self-discipline on the program, in terms of allocating memory, to limit the program's memory growth.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik ok, but how to impose a self discipline on the program in order not to exceed the memory that is safe to allocate? I am trying to limit the amount of memory used to store nodes by Gurobi and decreasing the number of Threads, but this cannot ensure that the program will ne be killed for all instances.

Comment: Well, this highly depends on the program itself. For example, a simple program: it allocates and grows a single vector. So: if you can determine that it's safe from OOM if the size of the vector is less than 1 million values, then code its logic accordingly. For more complicated programs it's obviously more difficult to figure out how to limit the memory growth, but that's basically how it's done: understand how the program allocates memory, then figure out how to limit it below a safe level. There is no single button, somewhere, that only needs to be pushed to do this. This requires analysis.

Comment: More detail is needed. How much memory on your computer? Any limits set with ulimit? What is the Gurobi log file before it gets killed?